# ¿Cómo generar registros en BBDD basado en un parámetro?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo en `SQL Server` una tabla que almacena el conteo de registros de otras tablas

[image: Tabla 1]

Necesito generar en otra tabla la cantidad de registros indicada por la columna conteo en la tabla de conteos, hasta el momento no he encontrado otra solución que no sea implementar un ciclo, lo cual quiero evitar por temas de rendimiento. ¿Qué otra alternativa puedo tener?

Comment: qué estructura tiene la "otra tabla" a la que debes insertar registros?, por favor muestra un ejemplo del resultado que quieres

Comment: por favor pon un ejemplo del resultado que quieres

Comment: Le da igual la estructura, solo quiere un campo computado como sea en otra tabla difernete (una tabla que no tendrá creada). A mi personalmente no me suena que se pueda aunque lo que si puedes es usar una "vista" en sql

Comment: Haber lo intento explicar... Necesito crear en otra tabla (sin importar la estructura ) la cantidad de registros indicada por mi tabla de conteos.. la estructura de la tabla donde  voy a registrar la cantidad indicada ,... es cambiante, pero se debe cumplir a exactamente con la cantidad indicada en la tabla de conteos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no es muy complicado, me suena a que necesitas una tabla de números y luego hacer un `JOIN`:

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.object_id)
    FROM sys.objects A
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects B
) --tabla de números, si necesitas más, simplemente haz otro CROSS JOIN
SELECT  B.*,
        A.RN
FROM CTE1 A
INNER JOIN dbo.TuTabla B
    ON A.RN <= B.Conteo
ORDER BY B.Id, A.RN;
```

[**Acá hay un demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=72da5f610ee6cb74e2331dd44d22cca1) de esto. Y una muestra de los resultados:

```
╔════╦════════════════╦════════╦════╗
║ Id ║     Tabla      ║ Conteo ║ RN ║
╠════╬════════════════╬════════╬════╣
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 31 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 32 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 33 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 34 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 35 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 36 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 37 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 38 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 39 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 40 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 41 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 42 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 43 ║
║  1 ║ ANA_BIOQUIMICA ║     44 ║ 44 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  1 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  2 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  3 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  4 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  5 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  6 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  7 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  8 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║  9 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 10 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 11 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 12 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 13 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 14 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 15 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 16 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 17 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 18 ║
║  2 ║ ANA_CITOLOGIA  ║     19 ║ 19 ║
╚════╩════════════════╩════════╩════╝
```

Comment: Gracias... me fue de utilidad...

Comment: Dale click en el check verde para que aceptes la respuesta :D